# Rawurclencode changes / to %2F

Tags: php, pdf

As the title say, I'm trying to show a pdf file in the browser, making the link via rawurlencode, but have some error. `linkVedlegg` is an attribut in the database wich is filled with:

```
filer/38/askeladdens PDF fil for opp.pdf
```

The url should be:

```
localhost/upload/filer/38/Askeladdens%20PDF%20fil%20for%20opp.pdf
```

As filer and 38 is catalogs. but the Rawurlencode changes the url to:

```
localhost/upload/filer%2F38%2FAskeladdens%20PDF%20fil%20for%20opp.pdf
```

So it can't find the file.

why is this happening?

Here's the code:

```
<p><a href= <?php
// Getting link from databasen
$sql = "select linkVedlegg from oppgaver where oppgavePK='".$_SESSION['oppg']."'";
// Execute sql
$res = $db->query($sql);
// test
if (!$res) {
throw new Exception("Database Error [{$db->errno}] {$db->error}"); }
// Fills $rad with link
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
$rad= rawurlencode($row['linkVedlegg']);
// Writes out the right URL with the path to the files and connect it to the linktext
echo ($rad); }?> > Se vedlegg </a> </p>
```

Comment: Why? The spaces isn't the problem, the character / is

Comment: You're URL-encoding data twice. The code you share does it once. Thus the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: Can't understand that. If it's urlencoding you are thinking of, in that case there are no other.

Comment: Consider splitting your raw partial URL `filer/38/askeladdens PDF fil for opp.pdf` into a part which does not need encoding (`filer/38/` in your case) and a part which needs encoding: `askeladdens PDF fil for opp.pdf`; then apply `rawurlencode` to the latter part only and concatenate.

Comment: That did work! Was i little unsure how i should do this since every user get's his own catalogue in the filer-catalogue. But width use of the id i managed to fix it! Thank you ver much.